# Saving PDFs sent by DocuSign Connect

Tags: docusignapi

I'm able to parse the XML received from Docusign Connect properly, but I'm running into issues saving the PDFBytes into a PDF file to be viewed later. The following is a snippet of the code I'm using.

```
$filename = $xml->DocumentPDFs->DocumentPDF->Name;
$contents = $xml->DocumentPDFs->DocumentPDF->PDFBytes;
file_put_contents($filename, $contents);
```

When I try opening the file, the viewer doesn't understand what the file is.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Are you sure that the `PDFBytes` on the $xml structure you have are not corrupt?  Have you tried with different envelopes and are getting the same thing?  Without any other info on the surface it looks like that should work...

Comment: I actually found the reason why... file_put_contents($filename, $contents); needs to be file_put_contents($filename, base64_decode($contents)); because it's base64 encoded.

Comment: Oh nice catch, you should answer your own question then so that the community benefits from your answer

Comment: I can't answer my own question because I have less than 10 reputation :P

Answer (score 2):

(Posting your comment as an answer, so that others can benefit from this information in the future.)

**$contents** is base64-encoded, so you need to use **base64_decode** -- like this:

```
file_put_contents($filename, base64_decode($contents));
```